# Twitter Feed Stopped Working?

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have been using this code on my site for a while and it's now stopped working?

I know it's something to do with the API version now updated but need to know what is needed to fix this script?

Code originally from:
http://www.queness.com/code-snippet/6495/get-the-latest-twitter-tweet-with-jquery

```
$(function() {

// set your twitter id
var user = 'quenesswebblog';

// using jquery built in get json method with twitter api, return only one result
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + user + '&count=1&callback=?', function(data)      {

    // result returned
    var tweet = data[0].text;

    // process links and reply
    tweet = tweet.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, function(url) {
        return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });

    // output the result
    $("#tweet").html(tweet);
}); 

});
```

Thanks,

TJ.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news from Twitter HQ that the url now returns http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxx now only returns "Sorry, that page does not exist" from Oct 12th 2012.

You will need to use https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=xxx&count=2 and modify your remaining code however I believe that this will be removed by March 2013 and you will need to use oAuth to validate.

HTH